# How to use ontrigger for teleport or portal in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner of C# and still learning.
I just want know why it is no working at all.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Portal)
{
    Debug.Log ("waaa1111aa");
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Portal.tag == "Player")
    {
        Portal.transform.position = new Vector3(11.5781f, 9.681356f, 1.419181e-07f);    
    }
}
```

the code is like a door portal for my hero
if im going to remove the input code indeed it will work
but that was not i meant to do is there a way
that when i hit the door im going to getbuttondown or getkeydown first

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave us some clue as to what this code is *supposed* to do and what exactly you mean when you say it's not working? Is there an exception / compiler error?

Comment: owh my god  yeah forgot that sorry, what that code use was its like a door for my hero that when the hero hit it then press the jump button it will teleport the hero to a location. it will work if im going to remove the input code but that was not the thing i wanted " sorry not good in english

Answer (score 2):

This code looks like it is going to move the portal object, not the object to which this code is attached.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Portal)
{
    Debug.Log ("teleporting");         
     {
         gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(11.5781f, 9.681356f, 1.419181e-07f);    
      }
 }
```

It would be a more robust system if you put the destination location onto a gameComponent on the portal object so you don't have to hard-code the destination. Say your portal has a component on it called PortalComponent, which has a Vector3 field called "Destination":

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Portal)
{
    PortalComponent p = Portal.gameObject.GetComponent<PortalComponent>();

     if (p != null) {
     Debug.Log ("teleporting");         

         gameObject.transform.position = p.Destination;    
      }
 }
```

Comment: i wanted to use the code you wanted me to use cause indeed im having a hard coded right now, but the problem was i kinda dont get it where should i placed that sorry and thx for replyng :(

Comment: Player should have the original script with OnTriggerEnter, the portals have the PortalComponent script

Comment: And yeah - do button tests in OnTriggerStay !

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OnTriggerStay instead and test for the teleport buttons there.